# Creating a Network Graph using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I need some help getting started using igraph in R. I have a .csv file with three columns:

1. the first column is a String that represents the "from" node,
2. the second column is a String that represents the "to" node, and then
3. the third column is a Double that represents the strength of the relationship.

I have the file read into R, and I tried turning it into a dataframe and graphing it that way, but it didn't work. 
My final goal is to turn this .csv file into a weighted network graph, but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: This question will likely get closed or at least heavily downvoted.  You've given no data or code to work with.  Have a look at these posting guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 15):

This (adapted example from the `igraph` documentation) should get you started:

```
# Load package
library(igraph)

# Make up data
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David", "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        weight=c(4,5,5,2,1,1))
# Alternatively, you could read in the data from a similar CSV file as follows:
# relations <- read.csv("relations.csv")

# Load (DIRECTED) graph from data frame 
g <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=TRUE)

# Plot graph
plot(g, edge.width=E(g)$weight)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

One topic in `igraph` that does not get enough attention is the question of how to control layout. In your case, presumably you want the separation between the nodes to be related to the strength of the relationship between them. This can be controlled using the `layout` parameter in `plot.igraph(...)`.

There are about a dozen algorithms for calculating layout, but the one I find most useful is `layout.fruchterman.reingold(...)`, which basically treats the edges as a set of springs with spring constant set by the `weights` parameter to the function. The algorithm then fixes the location of the vertices by allowing the springs to come to equilibrium. This means that vertices with high edge weight will, in general, be closer together.

So, using the graph defined in the other answer:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
set.seed(1)
plot(g)
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(g,weights=E(g)$weight^3))
```

[image]

You can see from the graph on the right that Bob, Alice, and Cecil are closer to each other because the "strength of the relationship between them", e.g. the edge weights, is greater (4-5). Esmeralda and Alice are separated by a large gap, because the edge weight is only 1. Note also that Bob and David are closer together than you might expect, given that their edge weight is the same as that for Esmeralda and Alice. This is because their separation is influenced by the fact that David is also linked to Alice.